# custom card component Vue.js + Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js

[image: card exemple]

I found this card component example on the internet and would like to build something similar with Vuetify. I'd like to know what is the best/easiest way to approach this? Using default v-card and add custom elements/css inside.Or building the whole card with Vuetify gid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate something similar with an outlined `v-card` with only a `v-card-text` child. The top section looks like an outlined `v-alert` with left [border](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/alerts/#border). Use `v-row` and `v-col` (`col-auto` on all) grid inside, with `v-spacer` for the whitespace after first column. Bottom section will also have the grid. You could also put the `v-alert` inside `v-card-title` for similar effect but I don't think the banner alert is appropriate as a "card title".

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify is a Vue UI library that provides ready-to-use components saving the developer time. So if the components Vuetify makes available to you are fine out of the box, you're fine, otherwise there's nothing wrong with adding custom CSS. In reference to the screenshot you attached, vuetify allows you to make that card in a practically identical way. In addition to studying the functioning of the basic components, I recommend that you take a look at the ready-made CSS classes that Vuetify provides you. Thanks to those you can do a lot of things. I hope I was helpful.